# How to center the java print dialog

Tags: java, swing

I'm using the java print option.In their unable to center the printer dialog in the monitor.

```
PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog
```

Printer dialog always comes in the corner of monitor.Please help ?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot center the native dialog. But the swing dialog can be centered as it shown below,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below code to center the Java print dialog.

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
PageFormat pf = pj.printDialog(aset);
```

Comment: Another small  problem is can we change the font size of print dialog ?

Comment: Small problem i have.My dialog come on center to monitor.But we are using multi monitors.If my client runs on second monitor still dialog comes and center on the first monitor.Any way we can locate relative to monitor.

Comment: Another problem is in our module we have a screen server.Some time screen server can come when print dialog is their.can we close the print dialog programmatically ?